# Dynamically setting localRepository option in Maven

Tags: maven

Is it possible to set local repository path using profiles in Maven?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502849/maven-local-repository-using-environment-variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, setting the local repo path can only be done in `settings.xml` using `settings/localRepository`, or passed in command line with the `-Dmaven.repo.local` param...

See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3588 comments for additional info