# How to enable maven artifact caching for GitLab CI runner?

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We use GitLab CI with shared runners to do our continuous integration. For each build, the runner downloads tons of maven artifacts.

Is there a way to configure GitLab CI to cache those artifacts so we can speed up the building process by preventing downloading the same artifact over and over again?

Comment: Maven has a cache usually under `$HOME/.m2/repository` or can be configured via `mvn -Dmaven.local.repo=Path`?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Gitlab CI allows you to define certain paths, which contain data that should be cached between builds, on a per job or build basis (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) for more details). In combination with khmarbaise's recommendation, this can be used to cache dependencies between multiple builds.

An example that caches all job dependencies in your build:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"

maven_job:
  script:
    - mvn clean install
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed `-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2` in `-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository`

Comment: It's 2017 now and for the newcomers:

`GitLab` maintains [a nice project][1] with sample configurations of their CI runner. The [sample Maven project][2] file demonstrates how to cache the maven artifacts.


  [1]: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/tree/master
  [2]: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/blob/master/Maven.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Is it possible to share cached artifacts between projects?

Comment: Update to @zloster links. Gitlab deprecated the project in those links. Updated link is https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates

Comment: Update to @antonkronaj link. Project 'gitlab-org/gitlab-ce' was moved to ['gitlab-org/gitlab-foss'](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates).

Comment: We used the definition with -Dmaven.repo.local=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2/repository. But the problem is, that sometimes (!) the CI_PROJECT_DIR is not resolved (not matter whether you use curly brackets or not), which end up in the path /.m2/repository. But you cannot cache anything outside of the project folder. Because of this we use -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository, as the maven commands are always executed withing the project folder(s).

Comment: I tried the mentioned options in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Maven.gitlab-ci.yml and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 18):

According to the conversation over on [GitLab's issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/327), I managed to change the Maven local repository path and put it into `./.m2/repository/` directory, which is we will then persist between runs by adding this global block to the CI config:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - ./.m2/repository
  # keep cache across branch
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
```

Unfortunately, according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8755707/2713162) the maven local repository path can only be set on every run with `-Dmaven.repo.local` or by editing your `settings.xml`, which is a tedious task to do in a gitlab-ci configuration script. An option would be to set a variable with the default Maven options and pass it to every run.

Also, it is crucial that the local Maven repository is a child of the current directory. For some reason, putting it in `/cache` or `/builds` didn't work for me, even though someone from GitLab claimed it should.

Example of a working `gitlab-ci.yml` configuration file for Maven + Java:

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/repository"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"

cache:
  paths:
    - ./.m2/repository
  # keep cache across branch
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "mvn clean compile $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/

unittest-job:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build-job
  script:
    - "mvn package $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/

integrationtest-job:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build-job
  script:
    - "mvn verify $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "target/*.jar"
```

Comment: Is it possible to share cached artifacts between projects in Gitlab?

Comment: There is a trouble : where do you use `$MAVEN_OPTS` var ?

Comment: @GGO `MAVEN_OPTS` is a well-known environment variable automatically used by Maven.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer didn't do it for me.

As **zlobster** mentioned, the guys at GitLab have this amazing [repository](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/blob/master/Maven.gitlab-ci.yml#L30) where you can find a proper example of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file used for Maven projects.

Basically, what you need are these lines:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
```

Keep in mind that if you decide to a add a local cache for a certain job, the global one added above will be replaced. More on this [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the local cache overwrites the global one. This caused the .m2 folder to be deleted on each run so that all dependencies will be downloaded again.

Answer (score 7):

You can add cache folder to gitlab-ci runner configuration and pass it to maven.

**/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml**

```
[[runners]]
...
  [runners.docker]
  ...
   volumes = ["/cache", "/.m2"]
  ...
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=/.m2"

build:
  script:
    - mvn package
```

Comment: The only way it worked for me is by adding the second volume on config.toml as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 6):

If you are using kubernetes as executor for gitlab-runner, you can also use the maven cache. I chose to have a persistent cache on NFS with k8s PV (but other volume type are supported by [gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#using-volumes)). The following configuration doesn't use the [cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#cache) gitlab feature because of persistence offered by NFS.

1) create a PersistentVolume on your cluster, ex here with NFS (adapt to your persistence layer and your options) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: gitlabrunner-nfs-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  mountOptions:
    - nolock
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  nfs:
    path: /gitlabrunner
    server: 1.2.3.4
```

2) Reference the PV to get a claim as a volume in the runner pod :

```
[[runners.kubernetes.volumes.pvc]]
  name = "pvc-1"
  mount_path = "/path/to/mount/point1"
```

Note (03/09/18) : A command line option for these paramaters doesn't exist yet. There is a open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2578).

3) Specify the same path for the gitlab-runner cache :

```
[[runners]]
  executor = "kubernetes"
  # ...
  cache_dir = "/path/to/mount/point1"
```

or

`--cache-dir "/path/to/mount/point1"` in interactive mode

4) use the "/path/to/mount/point1" directory in the `-Dmaven.repo.local` option

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use a host volume to share my `.m2` repository directory. This also had the advantage of sharing over my `settings.xml` file (which not everyone may want). I found this to be faster than using the `cache` solutions mentioned.

```
[[runners]]
  [runners.docker]
    volumes = ["/home/<user>/.m2:/root/.m2"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another approach. Do not use gitlab cache and use custom (per project) docker image.

Some details:

First of all, you need to create a maven docker image where all (or most of) required for your project dependencies are presented. Publish it to your registry (gitlab has one) and use it for any job running maven.

To create such an image I usually create an additional job in CI triggered manually. You need to trigger it at initial stage and when project dependencies are heavily modified.

Working sample can be found here:

https://gitlab.com/alexej.vlasov/syncer/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
- this project is using the prepared image and also it has a job to prepare this image.

https://gitlab.com/alexej.vlasov/maven/blob/master/Dockerfile
- dockerfile to run maven and download dependencies once.

The pros:

- don't need to download dependencies each time - they are inside a
  docker image (and docker layers are cached on the runners)
- don't need to upload artifacts when job is finished
- cache are not downloaded in jobs don't use maven

Comment: Hi Alexey, the links in your answer seem to be down. Could you share the content of these files in your answer?

Comment: @Jodiug It seems like some GitLab access issue. These projects are public and should be accessible to anyone. Can you try one more time?

Comment: The second link works now - the first one does not (404). Perhaps the repository has become private?

Comment: Nope, it's public. I have changed to private and backed it up to the public. Please try now. @Jodiug

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare MAVEN_OPTS in variables section when you use CI_PROJECT_DIR variable (The full path where the repository is cloned and where the job is run)

```
cache:
    key: maven-cache
    paths:
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/
```