# Configure cache on GitLab runner

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I don't manage to configure a cache directory, but somehow it does not work. I'm not even sure it takes the config.toml file.

my config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  cache_dir = /tmp/gitlab-runner-cache
```

... both on /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml and in ~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml

my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

cache:
  key: "myCache"
  paths:
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR]/.m2/

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2

stages:
  - build
  - acceptance

maven-build:
  image: maven:3.3-jdk-8
  stage: build
  script: "mvn clean package"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

maven-acceptance:
  dependencies:
    - maven-build
  image: maven:3.3-jdk-8
  stage: acceptance
  script: "mvn verify"
```

When I try:
   gitlab-runner exec shell maven-build

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not create cache adapter               error=cache factory not found: factory for cache adapter "" was not registered
```

The build is successful, but the .m2 repository is not cached...

Therefore, I have 2 questions:

1. How to know if gitlab-runner actually takes my config.yml?
2. What is a correct config for caching?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a good thread explaining the cache configuration for maven https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785154/how-to-enable-maven-artifact-caching-for-gitlab-ci-runner/

Comment: The error I get is: `level=warning msg="Cache config not defined. Skipping cache operation."` But the cache *does* get stored to a local folder. Version: `GitLab Community Edition 14.5.2`.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue just now. I am not sure which version of Gitlab you use, but version 12 supports either an S3-compatible storage or GCS as the cache provider ([see thes docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscache-section)), but no local cache folder like `cache_dir = /tmp/gitlab-runner-cache`.

The issue I had was, that I forgot to add `Type = "s3"` to the `[runners.cache]`section of the Runner configuration:

```
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = ...
```

Comment: So when I get it right... You need S3 or GCS storage to make a persistent shared/private cloud cache... If you have neither of both, cache is only locally in the container. Correct? So can I delete the "runner.cache" section to avoid the "ERROR: Could not create cache adapter"?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. Instead of using AWS or GCS, you may spin up a local Minio S3-compatible server and use it as the S3 cache. This way all caches stay on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error ("cache factory not found") and the problem was that the value of `cache_dir` was not included in the `[runners.docker]` / `volumes` config.

The [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) about `cache_dir` says:

> If the docker executor is used, this directory needs to be included in its volumes parameter.

After adding the path to `volumes` the cache works without S3 or other distributed cache.

Here are the relevant parts of the working `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
[[runners]]
  executor = "docker"
  cache_dir = "/home/gitlab-runner/cache"
  [runners.docker]
    volumes = ["/cache", "/home/gitlab-runner/cache"]
```

Comment: Actually struggling with this right now - unfortunately, your fix didn't work for me. I'm curious what version of the runner you have? And are you running `exec shell` or `exec docker`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm running `gitlab-runner` 12.4.1 (Debian package). By `exec` you mean `executor`? I'm using `docker`.

Comment: @MichaëlWitrant  What's the purpose of having both `/cache` and `/home/gitlab-runner/cache` defined as volumes? Why not just the latter?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it was already there so I just kept it and added the missing volume.

Comment: See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/36877#note_1572421182 for the correct solution for passing cache around in a local runner between jobs.