# Gitlab CI for MAVEN project with Docker Image

Tags: java, maven, selenium, docker, gitlab

I have project on java, where i have my tests. Now i have `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn test-compile compile
  tags:
    - mytag
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
```

Each time, when i am making commit in my repo, i am waiting a lot of time, when it will download all depencies. In docker we can use volume option. The question:
Can i download and compile locally this project for creating of `.m2` directory, and can i use this directory in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`. If yes, can you help me how, because i have not found in internet examples according to it.

I made changes in my `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "maven:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache","/M2/.m2:/root/.m2"]
    shm_size = 0
```

`/M2/` is a dir, with gitlab-runner owner. But it does not help, how we can see:

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-parent/1.3/hamcrest-parent-1.3.pom (2.0 kB at 20 kB/s)
Downloading from atlas: https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/maven/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.8.1/selenium-java-3.8.1.pom
Downloading from nio: http://clojars.org/repo/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.8.1/selenium-java-3.8.1.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.8.1/selenium-java-3.8.1.pom
Progress (1): 2.2/5.9 kB
Progress (1): 5.0/5.9 kB
Progress (1): 5.9 kB
```

Answer (score 2):

steps to take:
(host machine - the machine gitlab - runner installd on and the runner signed)

1. clone your repository on the host machine
2. compile it with maven
3. check that there is cached data folder under /root/.m2 on the host machine
4. fix your config.toml add this line

> volumes = ["/cache","~/.m2:/root/.m2"]

5. then add to .gitlab-ci.yml

> ```
> cache:
>   paths:
>     - /root/.m2/
> ```
>
> `variables:   MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2"`

the .gilatb.yml should look like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40024602/4267015

Answer (score 0):

- I build a "base docker image". Copy pom.xml to docker image and then run maven verify that image. This is dockerFile:

> ```
> FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine
> COPY pom.xml .
> RUN mvn verify clean --fail-never
> ```

- Open Terminal, then go to the project directory and run docker build:

> docker build -t xxx/projectName:base .

- Now "base docker image" has cached data.
- And then You can use "base docker image" in gitlab-ci.yml:

> ```
> image: xxx/projectName:base
>
> stages:
>   - build
>
> build:
>   stage: build
>   script:
>     - mvn test-compile compile
>   tags:
>     - mytag
>   only:
>     refs:
>       - dev
> ```